# Parsing the html page with images

Tags: python-3.x, beautifulsoup, request

In that video I provided, the man is parsing Google pictures.

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=MaWm1VpWj1A&list=LLiAY9i8Qha2Vx2j21Jk88PA&index=2&t=0s

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as bs
import random
import json
import lxml.html

ua = "Mozilla / 5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit / 537.36                     
(KHTML, как Gecko) Chrome / 58.0.3029.110 Safari / 537.36"

headers = {"User-Agent": random.choice(ua)}

r = requests.get("https://www.google.ru/search?tbm=isch&q=яблоко",                 
headers=headers)

html = r.content

soup = bs(html, "lxml")

images = soup.find_all("div", {"class": "rg_meta notranslate"})

images = [i.text for i in images]
images = [json.loads(i) for i in images]

print(images)
```

but I've got nothing but

> []
>
> Process finished with exit code 0

`soup` - displays html text, but `images = soup.find_all("div", {"class": "rg_meta notranslate"})` - displays nothing
I've already reviewed a lot of articles and I can find something everywhere and output it using `find_all` - I can't do anything and why, I don't know.
please help me understand what's going on

Comment: `soup.find_all("img")` is it work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To see the page as `requests` does, you have to turn off `Javascript` (`NoScript` is a browser extension that does it).

Then to grab the images you must identify them in the html :

[image: dev tools screenshot]

As you can see here, there are no elements with classes `"rg_meta"` and `"no_translate"`, that's why you get nothing.

As it has been suggested in the comments, you could use :

```
soup.find_all('img')
```

Alternatively, you could get the table with the class 'images_table', get its `'tbody'` element, and iterate on every `'tr'` and `'td'` elements to get the images.

Comment: Thank you for the quick and very clear answer, but then I have a new question - how to get a full image quality?